# Servicestack using TryParse by default

Tags: c#, parsing, servicestack, httprequest

We are using servicestack to serve our api over http and we'd like to have a more fault tolerant parsing of the incoming parameters. Consider the following route service:

```
[Route("/hello", "GET")]
public class Hello
{
  public int Integer { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
  public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
  public object Any(Hello request)
  {
    return new HelloResponse { Result = string.Format("Integer={0}", request.Integer)};
  }
}
```

(built on top of the simple console example from [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting))

The service works as expected but we'd like it to be more resilient towards incorrectly passed parameters. For instance, the following request works, defaulting the Integer parameter to 0:

```
http://localhost:1337/hello?integer=
```

...while this request throws a RequestBindingException:

```
http://localhost:1337/hello?integer=NaN
```

This seems to be caused by the default parsing built into to ServiceStack which uses an int.Parse rather than an int.TryParse, deep down in ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeBuiltin, and chokes on the textual input.

We would prefer a more fault tolerant parsing which simply ignored un-parsable arguments and assigned them the default value. We could hook into e.g. the json serialization 
and do something like this of each type:

```
JsConfig<int>.DeSerializeFn = (input) => {...}
```

but perhaps there is an easier way to get the desired behavior for servicestack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want more tolerant parsing, just use a string (which can hold any value) on your Request DTO, then convert it into an integer in your service.

Otherwise you can override the default binding in ServiceStack with your own [custom request binder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#create-a-custom-request-dto-binder). Finally you could potentially even use a PreRequestFilter which gets processed [just before the Request Binding](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) to sanitize the input, e.g:

```
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpRes) => {
    foreach (string key in httpReq.QueryString)
    {
        var val = httpReq.QueryString[key];
        if (val == "NaN")
            httpReq.QueryString[key] = "0";
    }
});
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer. It might not be the simple "just set this flag and everything is fault tolerant", but it lists my options